# How would I do this function in Excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

This function works perfectly in Google spreadsheets, but I can't figure out its equivalent in Excel.

```
=SUM(FILTER(Sheet5!G:G ,Sheet5!B:B=9 , SEARCH( "Company Name" ,Sheet5!E:E  ) ) )
```

I've read theres no equivalent to the filter function in Excel, whats the easiest way to translate this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an Excel expert but I think if you look at `sumif()` you'll be well on your way.

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT((Sheet5!B1:B100=9 )*(SEARCH( "Company Name" ,Sheet5!E1:E100  ))*(Sheet5!G1:G100 ))`  With SumProduct you do not want to use full column references, so make it as small as the largest the data rows can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the simplest way

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet5!G:G,Sheet5!B:B,9,Sheet5!E:E,"*Company Name*")
```

works easy, fast and no need to limit rows.